# How to use a relative path for LDFLAGS in golang

Tags: go, path, relative-path, cgo, ldflags

I am trying to build a golang program which uses a static lib (.a file)

the directory struct for my project as below

```
└─testserver
    ├─bin
    ├─pkg
    └─src
        ├─logging
        └─testserver
            ├─libtest.a
            └─test.go
```

the flags for cgo in test.go as below

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L /home/test/testserver/src/testserver -ltest
// #include "test.h"
import "C"
```

when I am using absolute path for LDFLAGS -L, it works fines, but when I change the path to a relative path, eg

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L ./testserver -ltest
```

and then run the command

```
go install testserver
```

it returns an error to me, and says "cannot find -ltest"

my question is how can I use a relative path in LDFLAGS ? , so that I can build the project in any path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You currently can't. The directory changes between the time the command is built, and linking. For now you either need to link to an absolute path, or use the `CGO_LDFLAGS` environment variable.

There was a commit just after go1.4 which added a `${SRCDIR}` variable which is replaced by the absolute path to the directory containing the source file at build  time. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7891. This will be in go1.5, and you can easily use it now by building Go from source.

Comment: As of go1.5.4, `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/testserver -ltest` works all right.

Answer (score 0):

It's really very great to use **${SRCDIR}** to solve the problem of ***relative path***.

In addition, the **${SRCDIR}** indicates the ***absolute path of current go file***.
Use command `go build -x .` to check the output.

```
$ go build -x .
...
cd /root/sourcecode/src/tcp/aes
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g" "-O2" "-L/root/sourcecode/src/tcp/aes/aes" "-laes" /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/tcp/aes/_obj/ -importpath tcp/aes -- -I $WORK/tcp/aes/_obj/ aes.go
cd $WORK
...
$ tcp/aes
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's incrrect, because the lib `libaes.a` locates the same as the go file.
Then I changed it, and passed.